# How to determine if an rgb color value (x,y,z) is within a gradient between to other rgb values

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have two colors

```
color1=[red:255, green:0, blue:0 ]

color2:[red:0,green:255,blue:0 ]
```

Imagine a gradient between those two colors, with color1 on the far left slowly transitioning to color2 on the right.

**How could I determine if a third color was in that color gradient band?**

Right now I determine it the long way by comparing ratios of change in a procedural way.

Is there an equation that would simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Determine how far along the third color is, in the red axis.

Step 2: Check to see if the third color is equally far along in the green and blue axes.

---

Explicit formulas:

Suppose the three red color values are $R_1, R_2, R_3$.  We set $$\lambda_R=\frac{R_3-R_1}{R_2-R_1}$$
This constant $\lambda_R$ should be between $0$ and $1$; otherwise we just answer "NO".

We can compute $\lambda_G$, $\lambda_B$ for the other two colors similarly.  If the three constants agree (up to rounding error) we answer "YES"; otherwise "NO".  The only thing to be careful about is if $R_1=R_2$; we don't want to divide by zero, so we just separately check to see if $R_3=R_1$ or not (as in the given example,for blue).

Answer (score 1):

It depends somewhat on how the gradient is carried out. The most likely case is that is is a simply a linear function
$$\mathbf{c}(t)=\langle 255,0,0\rangle + t\langle -255,255,0\rangle.$$
for $t\in[0,1]$ notice that $\mathbf{c}(0)$ is the vector corresponding to color one and $\mathbf{c}(1)$ is color two.

The important thing to notice here is that the second summand **always** adds the same amount to the second coordinate as it removes from the first. Therefore, you could use this simple criteria: a color $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is in the gradient if

1. $c=0$
2. $a+b=255$

---

**Edit:** I'll round out my answer just to make it a bit more general. If you are given two colors $\alpha=\langle r_1,g_1,b_1\rangle$ and $\beta=\langle r_2,g_2,b_2\rangle$, then every color on the straight-line gradient between them can be realized as a value of the function
$$\mathbf{c}(t)=\alpha+t(\beta-\alpha)=\langle r_1,g_1,b_1\rangle+t\langle r_2-r_1,g_2-g_1,b_2-b_1\rangle$$
again, as $t$ ranges over the interval $[0,1]$. As before, $\mathbf{c}(0)=\alpha$ and $\mathbf{c}(1)=\beta$.

Now if you have a vector $\gamma=\langle r_3,g_3,b_3\rangle$ and you want to determine whether this color lies on the the gradient, you would have to see if there is a $t\in[0,1]$ that satisfies the equation
$$\gamma=\alpha+t(\beta-\alpha)$$
which can be checked using the $\lambda_i$ used in @vadim123's answer.